# Not enough current draw through MOSFET

Tags: power, transistors, circuit-analysis, attiny

I am trying to control the current to a Raspberry Pi using a [MOSFET](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/PSMN2R0-30PL-1318146.pdf) and an ATtiny10. I am using a logic level MOSFET and it seems that the Pi needs about 250mA to turn on but it is only able to pull 120mA. My power source is 5V 3A. I have the circuit below. Any idea why I am unable to pull enough current to turn on?

[image]

[image]

[image]

NOTE: The answers below about breadboard causing Voltage and Current drops and the Pi rebooting due to over current draw are equally helpful. I accepted the answer that matched the Title question most.

Comment: Note that this is a follow-up to a previous question. The OP has changed to a different MOSFET (per recommendations) that should work. @SChand, please measure the gate and drain voltages. With a meter and scope if possible, just in case something is oscillating.

Comment: What are the voltages across the MOSFET's Gate to Source and Drain to Source when it is turned on?

Comment: @Mattman944 it is roughly 4.1-4.5V... I am seeing that the current supplied as well as the voltage is not very stable. The current goes 60mA, 90mA, 120mA, 200mA and then resets from 60mA. Not exactly those numbers but the current is not stable

Comment: @BruceAbbott the voltages you requested are in my previous reply :)

Comment: We need 2 measurements, as Bruce specified more clearly than I did. A Raspberry Pi draws a lot of current, be sure that your power supply current limit is set high enough.

Comment: Use a large series gate resistor to reduce gate slew rate Ic=CdV/dt and current surge due to 5V/ESR of caps which is more than the steady start current. So , source shutdown may be in effect.  If Cap ESR is 0.1 Ohm then surge current is 50A

Comment: @Mattman944 the voltage using multimeter was same for G-S and G-D. It changes from 4.5V to 4.4 to 4.2 and starts over again at 4.5V. Pi only uses roughly 250mA to boot up and I am supplying 3A. I even gave it 5A but still same results with bouncing voltage and current values.... Circuit is on a 1" x 3" breadboard if that means anything and when I measured G-S and G-D with power supply off there was some small voltage around 100mV

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I added a Series resistor of 1K to the Gate but still have oscillating I and V

Comment: Use 100k and 0.1uF and keep increasing. or get an ICL

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 used  .1uF w/ 100k Ohm and 600k Ohm but results remain the same

Comment: iF5V drops you got supply issues

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 That's odd since I am using a DC Regulated Power Supply. Shouldn't there always be some voltage drop across this type of circuit?

Comment: Can you post a picture of you setup?  Some Raspberry Pi's can draw a few amps, and your power supply may need to be set 50% higher to accommodate the startup. Also, If you are using a solderless breadboard, the cheap Chinese ones can have 1 ohm of resistance, you will get unacceptable voltage drops at a few amps.

Comment: @Mattman944 sure I will add a pic. Also I bumped up current supply to 5A and still same behavior. I believe it is a cheap breadboard common in DIY.

Comment: It looks like the same breadboard that I had issues with recently. I was astonished at the voltage drops I saw at 1/2 amp. You need to solder the circuit.

Comment: I also have a breadboard that looks like that. It's horrible. 4.5V on both Gate and Drain at the same time suggests a poor connection from Ground to Source. Did you measure _directly_ across the MOSFET leads, or to another place on the board?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I measure it at the nodes on the breadboard not on the actual leads.

Comment: @Mattman944 I soldered the circuit and Pi seems to hold a steady current for now. Will have to test and validate if it is working long term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheap solderless breadboards are not adequate for circuits that draw several amps. The resistance between contacts can be as high as 1 ohm. At 2 amps (most RPi's will draw at least this much), a few volts drop can cause serious issues. A 2V drop in the MOSFET source path will cause the gate-source voltage to be 2V less than expected.

Comment: Thanks! I switched all components to a soldered board and have stable V and I throughout now. Definitely will be investing in a more reliable test board now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a low side switch with a 250 mA load current and a 2.5A active current limiter .  If you disable the current limiter the supply current spikes up to 17A in [this simulation.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000054999999999999995%201.1685319768402522%2050%20120%2028%0At%20144%20192%20112%20192%200%201%205.535880875094777e-8%205.53588089649778e-8%20100%0Ar%20304%20144%20304%20112%200%2020%0Ac%20336%20144%20336%20112%200%200.0001%20-0.000004552026839022005%0Aw%20160%20192%20160%20176%200%0AR%20304%20112%20304%2080%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0AR%2032%20160%200%20160%201%202%2010%202.5%202.5%200%200.5%0Ag%20160%20224%20160%20240%200%0Aw%20304%20224%20208%20224%200%0Af%20112%20160%20160%20160%2032%201.5%2020%0Ar%20160%20192%20160%20224%200%200.25%0Aw%20160%20224%20112%20224%200%0Aw%20112%20224%20112%20208%200%0Aw%20112%20176%20112%20160%200%0Aw%20160%20192%20144%20192%200%0Ar%20112%20160%2032%20160%200%201000%0Aw%20304%20144%20160%20144%200%0Aw%20208%20192%20208%20224%200%0Aw%20160%20224%20208%20224%200%0As%20160%20192%20208%20192%200%201%20true%0Aw%20304%20112%20336%20112%200%0Aw%20304%20144%20336%20144%200%0Ao%203%2016%200%2029442%200.618122539391649%200.0001%200%202%203%203%20Base%20Voltage%0Ao%204%2016%200%2012545%200.0001%202.472502396514303%200%202%204%203%20Supply%20Current%0Ao%2015%2016%200%2012546%204.999995571227625%200.0001%200%202%2015%203%20Drain%20Voltage%0A)

## Theory

Unknown Pi load capacitance causes low side switched supply to shut down from over current causing it to cycle on-off.

## Soft start solution

[image]

Here is what I think the problem is.
  (Ignore transistor which is bypassed now and current spike is 17A)
[image]